# Updating values in a pandas dataframe using another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, addition, division

I have an existing pandas Dataframe with the following format:

```
sample_dict = {'ID': [100, 200, 300], 'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [.1, .2, .3], 'c': [4, 5, 6], 'd': [.4, .5, .6]}
df_sample = pd.DataFrame(sample_dict)
```

Now, I want to update `df_sample` using another dataframe that looks like this:

```
sample_update = {'ID': [100, 300], 'a': [3, 2], 'b': [.4, .2], 'c': [2, 5], 'd': [.7, .1]}
df_updater = pd.DataFrame(sample_update)
```

The rule for the update is this:

1. For column `a` and `c`, just add values from `a` and `c` in `df_updater`.
2. For column `b`, it depends on the updated value of `a`. Let's say the update function would be `b = old_b + (new_b / updated_a)`.
3. For column `d`, the rules are similar to that of column `b` except that it depends on values of the updated `c` and `new_d`.

Here is the desired output:

```
new = {'ID': [100, 200, 300], 'a': [4, 2, 5], 'b': [.233333, .2, .33999999], 'c': [6, 5, 11], 'd': [.51666666, .5, .609090]}
df_new = pd.DataFrame(new)
```

My actual problems are using a little more complicated version of this but I think this example is enough to solve my problem. Also, In my real DataFrame, I have more columns following the same rules so I would like to make this method to loop over the columns if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add desired dataframe for easier verifying solutions?

Comment: alright, i'll add that.

Comment: And one question - `ID` values are unique?

Comment: yep. `ID` values are unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can use functions [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html) and [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
df = pd.merge(df_sample,df_updater,on='ID', how='left')

df[['a','c']] = df[['a_y','c_y']].add(df[['a_x','c_x']].values, fill_value=0)

df['b'] = df['b_x'].add(df['b_y'].div(df.a_y), fill_value=0)
df['d'] = df['c_x'].add(df['d_y'].div(df.c_y), fill_value=0)
print (df)
    ID  a_x  b_x  c_x  d_x  a_y  b_y  c_y  d_y    a     c         b     d
0  100    1  0.1    4  0.4  3.0  0.4  2.0  0.7  4.0   6.0  0.233333  4.35
1  200    2  0.2    5  0.5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  2.0   5.0  0.200000  5.00
2  300    3  0.3    6  0.6  2.0  0.2  5.0  0.1  5.0  11.0  0.400000  6.02

print (df[['a','b','c','d']])
     a         b     c     d
0  4.0  0.233333   6.0  4.35
1  2.0  0.200000   5.0  5.00
2  5.0  0.400000  11.0  6.02
```

Instead `merge` is posible use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df=pd.concat([df_sample.set_index('ID'),df_updater.set_index('ID')], axis=1,keys=('_x','_y'))
df.columns = [''.join((col[1], col[0])) for col in df.columns]
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
print (df)
    ID  a_x  b_x  c_x  d_x  a_y  b_y  c_y  d_y
0  100    1  0.1    4  0.4  3.0  0.4  2.0  0.7
1  200    2  0.2    5  0.5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  300    3  0.3    6  0.6  2.0  0.2  5.0  0.1
```

Comment: Please check values in column `d` - what is update formula? `old_c + (new_d / updated_c)` ?

Comment: yep. That's right. How efficient is this method? I think this will create a lot of unnecessary columns and might slow down computations.

Comment: There is problem you need align both dataframes by `ID` - so need `merge` or `concat` first and then do aritmetic operations.